# IDLE python 3.5 32-bit does not open

Tags: python, python-idle, python-3.5

After installing python 3.5 32-bit on a laptop running windows 10, and clicking the IDLE application, nothing happens at all.
As far as I can see, that is.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Nope, sorry.​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: Does python itself run?  If no, this is not an IDLE issue at all; change the title and remove the python-idle tag.  If yes, enter `import idlelib.idle` at an interactive (`>>> `) prompt.  Or open a console window and enter `python -m idlelib` at the `<path> >` prompt.  What happens? What error message if any?